# log4j 1.2.12 prints the strings incrementally :O

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x, appender, fileappender

In my project the **log4j (1.2.12)** prints the strings incrementally at any level.
For example:

> 17-09-2018 15:08:18 DEBUG AnagraficaServiceImpl:32 - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK
>   10214967 [default task-32] DEBUG [...].model.service.impl.AnagraficaServiceImpl  - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK
>   10214967 [default task-32] DEBUG [...].model.service.impl.AnagraficaServiceImpl  - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK
>   10214967 [default task-32] DEBUG [...].model.service.impl.AnagraficaServiceImpl  - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK
>   10214967 [default task-32] DEBUG [...].model.service.impl.AnagraficaServiceImpl  - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK
>   10214967 [default task-32] DEBUG [...].model.service.impl.AnagraficaServiceImpl  - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK
>   10214967 [default task-32] DEBUG [...].model.service.impl.AnagraficaServiceImpl  - :::: Riferimenti operazione UPLOAD OK salvati con esito OK

as you can see, the lines have the same timestamp.
In this case there are 7 log strings, and at the next operation through the "*[...].model*" library, they will become 8, then 9, then n !!!! until the server.log is not saturated and then jboss (AS 1.7) reboots !!
**Please help me !!!**

If something like this happened to you, and you need more info on versions and details of `log4j.properties`, `jboss-deployment-structure`, `standalone.xml`, `pom.xml` or any other configuration you ask as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!!

fyi: in the library there was the BasicConfigurator.configure() method (log4j), that creates an appender to the log in the root of the stdout. Removed the instruction, the problem is solved! :D